# How to hide controller name in the url in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

so the thing is I'm using .htaccess to hide the index.php but I still get the controller name in the url like that: http://example.com/name_controller/about
My question is: is it possible to hide the name of the controller, so that only method is shown? hxxp://example.com/name_controller/about

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can define a custom route in config/routes.php - for example:

```
$route['about'] = 'name_controller/about';

Then, http://example.com/about
goes to http://example.com/name_controller/about
```

See [Hiding the controller’s method name in the URL?](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/52675/#257234) in the CI forums for more information.

Comment: Is this required to be done for all the pages, there isn't any automated solution which will apply the rule to all the routes by default?

Answer (score 5):

You can add an entry in the `/system/application/config/routes.php` file:

```
$route['about'] = "controller_name/about";
```

Answer (score 2):

$route['default_controller'] = "xxx";

## home

$route['**home**'] = "**xxx/home**";

### function_name/parameter0/parameter1/parameter2

$route['**Collection/(:any)**'] = "**xxx/Collection/$1**";

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this: (config/routes.php)

Code:
$route['((photos|blogs).+)'] = "$1";

$route['([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)'] = "user/profile/$1";

it is ok correct solutions for common.

Comment: please try to clarify the last phrase, it sounds very unclear

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code in the **`/application/config/routes.php`** file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['(?i)about'] = "Home/about";
$route['(?i)login'] = "Home/Login";
$route['(?i)products'] = "ProductController/ProductList";
$route['(?i)addproduct'] = "ProductController/AddProduct";
$route['(?i)editproduct'] = "ProductController/EditProduct";
$route['(?i)products/(:any)'] = "ProductController/ProductList/$1";//search product list perameters.
```

> 100% It work..