# How to remove controller name from the URL in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have controller named “profile” and the URL for user profile is
www.example.com/profile/user

I am already using the rerouting of codeigniter in the routes file

```
$route['profile/(:any)'] = "profile/index";
```

what I am looking is to remove the profile controller name from the URL so it will be SEO and user friendly.

e.g

www.example.com/user

any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try any one of these

```
// url could be yourdomain/imran
$route['(:any)'] = 'profile/index/$1';
// url could be yourdomain/10
$route['(:num)'] = 'profile/index/$1';
// url could be yourdomain/imran10
$route['([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'] = "profile/index/$1";
```

Your class may look like this

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($id)
    {
        // $id is your param
    }
}
```

**Update :** (Be careful)

Remember that, if you have a class `Someclass` and you use `url` like `yourdomain/Someclass` then this will be routed to `profile/index/$1` if you have `$route['(:any)']` or `$route['([a-zA-Z0-9]+)']`.

Comment: I understand your point but I was thinking what if I add a rule in the route 
so that when no controller in the below list exist in the URL id display or goto profile index.

something like this

$route['^(?!ajax|welcome|blog|cms|contact|error_404|register|profile).*'] = "profile/index/$1";


but I am unable to get it right.


Any suggestions?

Comment: You may use `regex` and that's why I mentioned it in my answer, also you may re-route all the controllers with a `url`.

Comment: Sorry brother, right now I can't remember of any but you may search on Google or just re-route every controllers and you are welcome :-)

Comment: BTW, I have used same thing on [this project](http://alimsearch.co.uk/) and it's developed with [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and there all the routes are explicitly defined using `route` mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this in a route file:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "controller_name/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "controller_name/$1/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "controller_name/$1/$1/$1";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$route['user'] = 'profile/user';
```

Dont know any generic way to do it

Possible duplicate of [How to hide controller name in the url in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991323/how-to-hide-controller-name-in-the-url-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to add a catchall to the very end of your routes file. Like:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'profile/index';
```

This will catch everything that isn't caught by another route, so make sure this script contains logic to determine when a 404 should be presented.