# I want to remove controller name from url in every controller is it possible?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to remove controller name from every controller is it possible to do like this in route file.For single controller it is working fine for me what if I want to use for all controller in my project?

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'user';
$route['(:any)'] = "user/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "user/$1/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "user/$1/$1/$1";


$route['(:any)'] = "grant/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "grant/$1/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "grant/$1/$1/$1";
```

when I tried this its not working for me.

Comment: then how you are going to identify which request belongs to which controller ?, or all method names in your controllers are differrent ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove controller name from the URL in codeigniter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786855/how-to-remove-controller-name-from-the-url-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @Viral this is what I am asking is it possible or not?

Comment: This is not duplicate question please check my question ids for multiple controller not for single.

Comment: You are asking different thing, anything is possible, you can get all routes from database, or you can also have different names for your controller, set a `pre-controller` hook, you just need to decide which suits you best. For example, check [this](http://osvaldas.info/smart-database-driven-routing-in-codeigniter) @Ricky

Answer (score 0):

try this

You may try any one of these

```
// url could be yourdomain/imran
$route['(:any)'] = 'profile/index/$1';
// url could be yourdomain/10
$route['(:num)'] = 'profile/index/$1';
// url could be yourdomain/imran10
$route['([a-zA-Z0-9]+)'] = "profile/index/$1";
```

Your class may look like this

```
class Profile extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($id)
    {
        // $id is your param
    }
}
```

**Update :** (Be careful)

Remember that, if you have a class `Someclass` and you use `url` like `yourdomain/Someclass` then this will be routed to `profile/index/$1` if you have `$route['(:any)']` or `$route['([a-zA-Z0-9]+)']`.

Comment: is it possible to use for every controller ?if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

The code example you have provided will not work because the rules are exactly the same, for example:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "user/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "grant/$1";
```

There is no difference between the two so how is the application going to know where to route your request. It will just pick the first route that matches for all requests (user controller)

What you are trying to achieve is not possible unless (as @syed) has tried explaining above, there is a difference in at least the secondary parts of the url.

For example any numeric ids are passed to a user controller.

```
// url could be yourdomain/10
$route['(:num)'] = 'user/index/$1';
```

Any text based are passed to a different controller

```
// url could be yourdomain/imran
$route['([A-z]+)'] = "name/index/$1";
```

So on so forth.

Comment: thanks for your response.This is just what I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer

```
$route['(:any)'] = "user/$1"; //this is dynamically for user controller
```

for another controller in static way like this

```
$route['functionName'] = "controller/functionName";
$route['functionName'] = "controller/functionName";
```

this work fine for me for the time .I wish if this is possible dynamically