# How can I remove my controller name from the url using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

How can I remove the controller name from the URL when I access the index function of that controller?

This is my root :-

www.abc.com/sample/dev/

This is the controller name :-

home

Therefore :- If `www.abc.com/sample/dev/home` is the url, then it should become `www.abc.com/sample/dev/`. Also, how can I remove the `index.php` from this url :-

`www.abc.com/sample/dev/index.php`,

so that it becomes

```
www.abc.com/sample/dev/
```

as well.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365129/htaccess-remove-index-php-from-url and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786855/how-to-remove-controller-name-from-the-url-in-codeigniter

Comment: codeigniter. sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: index.php is a default. Just don't write it.