# how to remove controller name from url in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

url: example

```
controller_name/method_name/parameter

Colleges/index/autonomus-institute
```

controller:

```
public function index($university_type)
{
    $data['uni'] = $this->dependent->type($university_type);
    $data['student_id'] = $this->session->userdata('student_id');
    $this->load->view('header',$data);
    $this->load->view('university',$data);
}
```

view:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".university").click(function(){
            university = this.id;
            window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>colleges/index/"+university;
        });
    });
</script>
```

route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'test';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;

$route['index'] = "colleges/index/";
```

In this code I have controller having name index where I have load a view file having name university. Now, I want to remove controller name from url as I am define in my route.php file but its not working. So, How can I remove controller name from url ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: There is a typo mistake. It should be `colleges` instead of `college` as you written in your `url` `$route['university'] = "colleges/index/";`

Comment: but still its not working @AnkitSingh

Comment: What is your controller name?

Comment: my controller name is Colleges

Comment: is there any problem @AnkitSingh

Comment: Sorry! I didn't see. You are using `window.location.href= 'YOUR_URL'`. It will redirect you to the page. So change your url (remove `colleges/index/` form script in view) and check again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154288/discussion-between-omkara-and-ankit-singh).

Comment: Take a look at [How to remove controller name from the URL in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786855/how-to-remove-controller-name-from-the-url-in-codeigniter)

Comment: I am doing some changes in my question please visit one time if my parameter with (-) symbol it will show 404 error If I remove (-) it will show my page. @AnkitSingh