# Remove name of the route with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've set my default controller to my login page. After successful login, user will be redirected
`to www.mydomain.com/home.` Home is the name of my route and what I'd like to do now is to remove that
home with `.htaccess` - file.

Is this even possible?

My current .htaccess looks like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|css|js|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+home($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R]

RewriteRule ^$ index\.php?/home [L]
```

before the rules that you already have.

Comment: Tried that and now I got "This site has a redirect loop" - notification

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it from the .htaccess without getting the redirect loop.. So here are two solutions.

In past projects I've used the default controller (in your case Home) and then made a session checking library that would redirect to the login page if the user wasn't logged in. This was a simple check for `$this->session->userdata('auth') == true` which was set when the user logged in and the library method call was in the constructor for the default controller. Default controllers will have just the base url you're looking for.

OR

You can take a look at a previous answer from [another post by Justin Ethier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991323/how-to-hide-controller-name-in-the-url-in-codeigniter)

> You can define a custom route in config/routes.php - for example:
>
> $route['about'] = 'name_controller/about';
>
> Then, http://example.com/about
> goes to http://example.com/name_controller/about
>
> See Hiding the controller’s method name in the URL? in the CI forums for more information.